# Best way to parse "stringified" (sub-)Map<String,String>

Tags: json, oauth2, string

In my Auth Provider RegistrationHandler, I received an instance of the [Auth.UserData class](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex290/Content/apex_auth_plugin_part2.htm), filled with users data (in this case it is an external Salesforce user).
The usage is very comfortable, as long as you use the top-level attributes, or have primitive data types for every of the *attributeMap*. The *attributeMap* is a Map-String,String-, so it is easy to do something like:

`DateTime cDate = DateTime.valueOf(data.attributeMap.get('created_date'));`

The problem is when you have another Map as a value for the *attributeMap*, which will be converted by Salesforce into a single string:

`--> "photos":"{picture=https://c.na24.content.force.com/profilephoto/005/F, thumbnail=https://c.na24.content.force.com/profilephoto/005/T}"`

Salesforce describes this format as "a common format":

> If the registration handler wants to use the rest of the data, the Auth.UserData class has an attributeMap variable. The attribute map is a map of strings (Map-String, String-) for the raw values of all the data from the third party. Because the map is -String, String-, values that the third party returns that are not strings (like an array of URLs or a map) are converted into an appropriate string representation. The map includes everything returned by the third-party authorization provider, including the items automatically converted into the common format.

My question is, **has anyone ever parsed Maps from this common format?**

Comment: What do you mean by converted by Salesforce here: "The problem is when you have another Map as a value for the attributeMap, which will be converted by Salesforce into a single string:" ? What conversion process?

Comment: @PhilB : In my example with the attribute "photos" in attributeMap, I get another Map, but flattened out as a string. I can not get the thumbnail URL by simply calling data.attributeMap.get('photos').get('thumbnail').
The Auth.UserData class is populated (at least I suppose) with JSON data, which are transmitted between two orgs.

Here is the describing sentence from the Salesforce Docs (yellow box): "Because the map is -String, String-, values that the third party returns that are not strings (like an array of URLs or a map) are converted into an appropriate string representation."

Comment: Are you attempting to get the thumbnail url in JavaScript or Apex?

Comment: I am trying to get it in Apex. photo.thumbnail is just one example, the same format applies to other attributes.

Comment: not ideal, but why not just create a method to accept what property you want and parse the entire photos value as a string using String.split() and return the url?

Comment: I have something similar currently, where I parse it with search+replace into JSON format, but as you said "not ideal". There are other cases likes a map of URLs that are transferred, I would like to have something more reliable and faster, maybe a regex?!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a SSO implementation.

My approach was to rely on stiring regex and split methods. Way important was also the consistency of the data that I was receiving. So I could treat it properly.